# C# autocomplete to textbox from sql

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Good day everyone.

My question is how to automatically populate another text box based on the particular data entered within another. To explain further, my first text box is auto completing from a sql table with the name "code." beside that column is one called "description. " Based on that data being populated from the code column,how do I auto populate the second text box based on the value selected in the first text box? I really hope am making sense.

This is the code I have which is updating textbox1, this is working fine:

```
 private void liguaneaRxToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        this.liguanea_LaneTableAdapter1.Fill(this.pharmaciesDataSet1.Liguanea_Lane);
        try
        {

            string connectionString = "Data Source=LPMSW09000012JD\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Pharmacies;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            con.Open();
            string query = "SELECT Code FROM dbo.Liguanea_Lane";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            AutoCompleteStringCollection mycollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            while (dr.Read())
            {

                mycollection.Add(dr.GetString(0));

             textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = mycollection;
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Now this is the code for textbox2 which I want to fill in a value based on the value selected from text box 1.So for eg. In a query where I would write: "SELECT description FROM dbo.Liguanea_Lane where code= "whatever value." Where "whatever value" is what would be the input collected from the textbox1 and then return(populate) the description attached to in textbox2

```
 private void displayValIntoTextbox(string val ) //this function will auto complete the other textbox 
    {

        if (val == null) //this will check if the value is null 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("please enter a the correct code");
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                string connectionString = "Data Source=LPMSW09000012JD\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Pharmacies;Integrated Security=True";
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                con.Open();
                string query = "SELECT description FROM dbo.Liguanea_Lane where code= '"+val +"'"; // this query
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                AutoCompleteStringCollection mycollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
                if (dr.HasRows) // check if any info exist in database base off the query
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {

                        mycollection.Add(dr.GetString(0));

                    }
                    textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = mycollection;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(val);
                }

                con.Close();
            }
            catch (SqlException sql)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(sql.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope everyone follows. Oh it is also a Winform application

Comment: If displayValIntoTextbox(string val ) is for 2nd textbox i.e. textBox2 then, this function should have textBox2.AutoCompleteCustomSource = mycollection;

Comment: Even so the problem still isn't solved. Nothing is happening

Comment: I hope you are calling displayValIntoTextbox(string val )  from textbox1 text changed event.

Comment: Yes I am, same result

Answer (score -1):

Try this-

For Auto complete textbox from DB create a textbox control  with id 'txtAutoComplete'

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfCustomerId" runat="server" />
```

then add jquery plugin for ajax

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Add this ajax script for autocomplete

```
 $(function () {
    $("[id$=txtSearch]").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Default.aspx/GetCustomers") %>',
                data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.split('-')[0],
                            val: item.split('-')[1]
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (e, i) {
            $("[id$=hfCustomerId]").val(i.item.val);
        },
        minLength: 1
    });
});
```

in Default.aspx/GetCustomers method , write a C# code to get list of names from database.

for css add this style sheet reference

```
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css"
rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: this answer is for asp.net, the question is about windows forms.